# Maximum area of a triangle with two points on the circle and third point outside the circle

Tags: geometry, optimization, area

$A, B$ are two points on the circle $x^2+y^2=1.$ If a triangle is made connecting $A, B$ and point $C(5,2),$ what is the maximum area of the $\triangle ABC $ ?

I guess the maximum area will be obtained when $A, B$ are at the opposite side of the diameter and diameter $AB$ is perpendicular to $OC$, where $O$ is the origin. But I don't know how to justify or reject this guess.

Comment: Here's a rather boring but straightforward way: Let $A=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, $B=(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$, $C=(5,2)$. Find the area of $\Delta ABC$ as a function of $\theta$ and $\phi$, and maximize it using calculus. This should give you $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Your claim is true if you restrict segment $AB$ to be a diameter of the circle.
If $AB$ is a diameter,
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{area}(\triangle ABC)&=\text{area}(\triangle AOC)+\text{area}(\triangle BOC)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \sqrt{29}\cdot 1\cdot \sin \alpha+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \sqrt{29}\cdot 1\cdot \sin (180^{\circ}-\alpha)\\
&=\sqrt{29}\cdot\sin\alpha
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore, the area is maximized (given $AB$ is a diameter) when $$\sin\alpha=1\implies CO\perp AB.$$

Comment: It is true that AB must be perpendicular to OC but but it is not true that AB is must be the diameter. For maximum area, AB must be slightly less than the diameter. To see this, notice that your proof of perpendicularity will still work for any line parallel to the diameter.  That's why, in your answer the maximum with AB diameter is $\sqrt{29}\sin 90 = 5.385$ but in my answer we found a bigger triangle with area $5.474$ because we did not restrict AB to be the diameter.

Comment: Yes, I do not propose that OP's claim is correct. I am only suggesting that $CO\perp AB$ if we assume $AB$ to be the diameter. I have made no attempt to maximize the area in general because you have already done so. I was only addressing a part of OP's question (why his guess is partially correct).

Comment: OK got it. But in that case, the first line is misleading because the claim is true even if AB is not restricted to be the diameter. I suggest you remove the "only if" part words and the rest is then correct.

Comment: @NilotpalSinha Yes, that can lead to confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The circle is centered on the origin so the distance of the point $(5,2)$ from the center of the circle is $\sqrt{29}$. If we rotate the point $(5,2)$ anti-clockwise towards the $y$-axis keeping its distance from the origin fixed then the question is equivalent to finding the triangle with two points on the circle and the third point on the $y$-axis at $(0, \sqrt{29})$.

The triangle that maximizes the area will be symmetric about the $y$-axis with its base parallel to the $x$-axis (you may want to prove this separately). Let the coordinates the maximum area triangle be $(x,\sqrt{1 - x^2})$ and $(-x,\sqrt{1 - x^2})$. Then the length of its base is $2x$ and its height is either $\sqrt{29} + \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ if the point $(0, \sqrt{29})$ and the base are on opposite side of the $x$-axis or $\sqrt{29} - \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ is they are on the same side of the $x$-axis. Hence the maximum area is

$$
A(x) = \max\bigg(\frac{2x \big(\sqrt{29} \pm \sqrt{1 - x^2}\big)}{2} \bigg)
$$

Equating the first derivative to zero and checking for maxima, we find that the maximum area is

$$
\frac{1}{8}\sqrt{74 \sqrt{1073}- 506} \approx 5.474
$$